# how do I print my array using enhanced loops

Tags: java, for-loop, fibonacci

So as my program runs, it does some calculations for the Fibonacci sequence. I can easily print these 20 Fibonacci sequences out in the `for` loop, but I just want to do the calculations to fill the `Fib` array up and do the printing out in an enhanced loop. How can I do this with an enhanced for loop?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
                
        int[] Fib = new int[20];
        Fib[0] = 0;
        Fib[1] = 1;
        System.out.printf("%d %d", Fib[0], Fib[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < Fib.length; i++) {

            Fib[2] = Fib[0] + Fib[1];
            
            Fib[0] = Fib[1];
            Fib[1] = Fib[2];
            System.out.print(" "+Fib[2]); 

            for (int x : Fib) {
                 x = Fib[2];
                System.out.print(" "+x);;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains a few mistakes, and major are:

`Fib[2] = Fib[0] + Fib[1];` this should be `Fib[i] = Fib[i - 1] + Fib[i - 2];`
Another mistake is nesting for loops. The enhanced for loop should be after the loop with index `i`.

```
int[] Fib = new int[20];
Fib[0] = 0;
Fib[1] = 1;

for (int i = 2; i < Fib.length; i++) {
    Fib[i] = Fib[i - 1] + Fib[i - 2];
}

for (int number : Fib) {
    System.out.print(" " + number);
}
```

You can use `Arrays.toString(Fib)` instead of using a loop for printing the array.